# springMVC+thymleaf can not parse Message Expressions when use templateResolver to send email

Tags: templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

the application.properties is

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
# set to false for hot refresh, should be set to true in deployment
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

get template content is like this:

```
@Autowired
    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver;

private String getMailContent(EmailDTO email, EmailType type) {

    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    Context context = new Context(email.getLocale());
    context.setVariable("email", email.getAddress());
    return templateEngine.process("email/resetcontent", context);

}
```

the template is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>SIM : Reset Password</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
    <span th:text="#{reset.password.title}">Reset Password</span>
    <span th:text="${email}"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

th:text="${email}" can be parse but the th:text="#{reset.password.title}" is       ??reset.password.title_en_US??

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0yaO.png)

who can tell me why? thank you very much

Comment: see ${email} is binding with bean object and #{reset.password.title} is properties variable so its not pass solution is you need to get properties variable in your controller

Comment: yes, it's not a good solution, I use this method temporarily, if you think of any other way, please enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

if your using spring boot the default message resolver wil try to find the code "reset" for a "password" bean which have a "title" field.

you should use this code:

```
 <span th:text="#{resetPasswordTitle}">Reset Password</span>
```

Comment: it's really spring boot. I have tried, but still dose not work

Comment: have resolved, just because of have autowired templateEngine when the program start